# Non-interactive zero-knowledge proof for discrete logarithm without random oracle

Tags: public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs

Is there any non-interactive zero-knowledge proof for discrete logarithm without random oracle over the group $\mathbb Z_p$?

Comment: http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/J.Groth/NIZKJournal.pdf $\;$